# remove legend handles and labels completely

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Some plotting tools such as `seaborn` automatically label plots and add a legend. Removing the legend is fairly easy with `ax.get_legend().remove()`, but the handles and labels are still stored somewhere in the axes object. Thus when adding another line or other plot type, for which I want to have a legend, the "old" legend handles and labels are also displayed. In other words: `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` still returns the labels and handles introduced by f.i. seaborn.

Is there any way to **completely remove** the handles and labels to be used for a legend from an axis?
Such that `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` returns `([], [])`?

I know that I can set `sns.lineplot(..., legend=False)` in seaborn. I am just using seaborn to produce a nice example. The question is how to remove existing legend labels and handles in general.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'x': [0, 1, 0, 1], 
    'y': [7.2, 10., 11.2, 3.],
    'id': [4, 4, 7, 7]
})
# get mean per x location:
grpd = df.groupby('x').mean()

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='id', palette=['b', 'g'])
ax.get_legend().remove()

# this still returns the handles and labels:
print(ax.get_legend_handles_labels())
# Out: 
# ([<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x17c1c208f88>,
#   <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x17c1c1f8888>,
#   <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x17c1c20af88>],
#  ['id', '4', '7'])

# plot some other lines, for which I want to have a legend:
ax.plot(grpd.index, grpd['y'], label='mean')
# add legend, ONLY FOR MEAN, if possible:
ax.legend()
```

I tried manipulating the axes `ax.get_legend()` and `ax.legend_` objects, f.i. with `ax.legend_.legendHandles = []`, setting the labels, texts and everything else, but the "old" seaborn entries keep reappiering each time.

Since this is meant to be used within a module, it is **not applicable** to explicitly set a legend only containing the "mean"-entry. I need to "clear" everything happening in the backend to provide a clean API to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='id', palette=['b', 'g'])
```

to:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='id', palette=['b', 'g'], legend=False)
```

That way you also don't need to make the call to remove the legend as none is created in the first place.

**EDIT UPDATE:**

If you want to clear the legend handles and label, I think you'll have to do something like:

```
for line in ax.lines: # put this before you call the 'mean' plot function.
    line.set_label(s='')
```

This will loop over the lines draw on the plot and then set their label to be empty. That way the legend doesn't consider them and the `print(ax.get_legend_handles_labels())` will return empty iterables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please see the edit I added just a minute before you posted your answer. I guess you were already writing this answer when the I appended the information. :)

Comment: Many thanks! This solved the question for line plots. For pointplots and other plots (removing legend entries in genereal) I'll post a small extension of your solution in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks at mullinscr for the answer considering line plots. To remove legend labels in general, the labels of `lines`, `collections` (f.i. scatter plots), `patches` (boxplots etc) and `images` (imshow etc.) must be cleared:

```
for _artist in ax.lines + ax.collections + ax.patches + ax.images:
    _artist.set_label(s=None)
```

Please tell me, if I forgot to mention a specific kind of plot.

Answer (score 0):

**Another option is to do the following:**

```
ax.legend(handles=[], labels= [])
```

In this case, everything will be removed.

If for example you would like to only remove the first handle, you can do the following:

1. fetch the handles and labels of your plot:

```
h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()*
```

2. select the ones you want (here all except the first):

```
ax.legend(handles=[item for item in h[1:], labels= [item for item in l[1:])
```

This way, you can sort out the things you want.